# Boto3 ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI: How to handle errorcode "Throttling"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, tagging

I have written a python script that tags resources based on the passed servicename such as ec2, rds etc.
I have also flag 'all' that loops through 5 services (ec2, rds, iam, cloudwatch, dynamodb). There are around 650 ARNs to tag. 
I am aware that eacht .tag_resources() call takes not more than 20 arns. This problem I have already solved by using batches with the size of 20.

However, somewhen the return value contains the 'ErrorCode:Throttling' meaning that the AWS endpoint rejects the call.

What do you suggest for solving this issue? I tried it with time.sleep() but there is still the problem.

**EDIT:**
When exluding 'cloudwatch' it works perfeclty fine.

Here is the code of the helper function that performs the get.resource() call:

```
   def __tagHelper(self,arns,n,tags):

        batches = chunks(arns,n) # arns is a list containing 650 object, n = 20
        failedTagTrys=[]

        for batch in batches: # batch is of size 20        

                response = self.client.tag_resources(
                    ResourceARNList=batch,
                    Tags=tags
                )


                failedTagTrys.append(response['FailedResourcesMap'])


        # Clean up the list by removing empty dictionaries
        cleaned_FailedTagTrys=list(filter(None, failedTagTrys))
        return cleaned_FailedTagTrys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed the issue by using the AWS Resource Groups API.